# Close Apache connection (HTTP Download)

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a server that hosts large files, which users can download through the website. My problem is that if I disable the users account while the user is downloading file, the browser still will complete the download.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
1. Find the active process responsible for the current (download) connection
2. Kill the process - so that users browser fails to download the file.
```

How can I accomplish the first step? Does Apache, PHP or something else is responsible for the file transfer itself? I'm really clueless where to go from here.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with something similar a while ago. Apache is definitely processing the request for the download. I'd start with Apache's `mod_status` module.  Along with `top` and `ps` you might be able to find the process.

With the mod_status module turned on you can hit the page `http://your.server.name/server-status` and get all sorts of stats - [see the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html).

This is from the docs:

> [If] you wish to identify which requests or clients are causing the
>   problem ... First, ensure that you have ExtendedStatus set on, so that
>   you can see the full request and client information for each child or
>   thread ... Now look in your process list (using top, or similar
>   process viewing utility) to identify the specific processes that are
>   the main culprits